# Propagating Maven project properties to module that has a different parent

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Given the following minimal Maven multi-module structure. Module A is released together with the project and the other modules of the project. However, it inherits from some other parent POM (rather than the project POM).

```
                              |--------------------|
|-------------|               | module A that does | 
| project POM |--- module --->| *not* inherit from |
|-------------|               | project POM        |
                              |--------------------|
```

How can I propagate or synchronize properties from project POM to module A?

**Project**

```xml
<project>
    <parent>some-parent</parent>

    <groupId>some-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <revision>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>A</module> <!-- NOT inheriting from here -->
        <module>B</module> <!-- inheriting from here -->
    </modules>
</project>
```

**Module**

```xml
<project>
    <parent>some-OTHER-parent</parent>

    <!-- don't want to duplicate this, should be propagated from my-project -->
    <!--properties>
        <revision>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    </properties-->

    <groupId>some-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
</project>
```

**First attempt**

I wrote a small Groovy script for the GMavenPlus plugin that updates the module A `pom.xml` correctly synchronizing the *project* properties. However, even though the plugin runs in the `validate` phase (i.e. the earliest possible) it's too late. Maven already initialized the reactor with the old properties.

I want to give developers the convenience of simply running `mvn some-task` without having to worry about the properties being consistent. Managing those manually would be a pain.

8< ---------------

**off-topic: the complete use case**

I have a project ("my-project") that contains code other projects will consume: libraries, tools, utilities, etc (modules "B", "B+", "B++"). Furthermore, it contains a POM module (module "A") that said business projects will inherit from. That POM represents an opinionated blue-print that those projects should adhere to unless there are good reasons not to.

- I need the project POM "my-project" to build all the modules "B", "B+", "B++".
- The POM module "A"

  - has definitions very different from "my-project" as itself serves as a parent for the business projects.
  - (amongst others) lists all the modules "B", "B+", "B++", etc. in its dependency management section.
  - has to be released together with all the "B"s it manages -> that's why it lives in the same code project
  - shares a few external dependencies "X", "Y", "Z" with the project POM "my-project"

=> I need the versions for "X", "Y", "Z" in both the project POM "my-project" and in the POM module "A"

Comment: would you mind describing your final goal, not a synthetic case? Inheriting properties from multiple parents - this rabbit hole is too deep, however I believe the solution exists for real case.

Comment: The question is why does your child not inherit from your parent (`<module>A</module> `) ... that would solve the problem very easy?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov it's a very real use case, not a synthetic one. However, for the sake of simplicity and legibility I omitted everything that's not "relevant" for this Q. Relevant or not is very subjective, though. I'll amend the Q.

Comment: @khmarbaise oh yes, that would eliminate the problem altogether. If it were that easy, the Q here would not exist :)

Comment: @MarcelStör so, your actual goal is to manage versions of dependencies... maven way there is to create "dummy" [BoM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms) project and import it into both aggregator and "child" projects, as for the `revision` property maven recommends to manage in via [`.mvn/maven.config`](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html)

Comment: That's one of the goals - and BOMs are really helpful in that (we use them in several projects). What they don't offer is what we need in _this_ project: managing and passing on properties and plugin versions.